# A way to have Evernote notes indexed by the Windows Search Indexer?

Tags: windows-10, search, windows-search, search-indexing, evernote

As per title, I was wondering if there is a way to have the Windows Search Indexer index the Evernote database (and thus all the notes, their titles and content) so that hitting the Win key on the keyboard and typing something would search among those notes and their content, performing a full-text search.

Perhaps someone knows of a third-party app (something like [Launchy](https://www.launchy.net/)) that is able to index the Evernote database?

For those unfamiliar with it, Evernote is *"an app designed for note taking, organizing, task management, and archiving. It is developed by the Evernote Corporation, headquartered in Redwood City, California. The app allows users to create notes, which can be text, drawings, photographs, audio, or saved web content."*

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Keep the Evernote file / database in the USER folder and ensure USERs is in the index location in Windows Search.
2. Add the location of the existing Evernote database to the Windows Search location.

Index Options can be found in Control Panel

Rebuild the Index after making these changes.

[image]

Also you may need to set the Content search for the Evernote Database.

[image]

Comment: The thing is, Evernote seems to be storing the database somewhere in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Evernote` in Windows 10, but it's unclear exactly where. At this point, I even doubt the database would be searchable at all.

Comment: AppData is in your USER folder.  Look down this article - people say normal Windows Searching works.  https://discussion.evernote.com/forums/topic/120027-search-doesnt-work-on-windows-10/

Comment: You may also need to set the Content Attribute for the Evernote Database. Indexing advanced options.